# Http analyzer free alternative?

Tags: networking, http, monitoring, analysis, sniffing

Are there any free alternatives for this app ??

http://www.ieinspector.com/httpanalyzer/

It's great, it monitors all open http requests and downloaded size.

Any suggestions please ??

Answer (score 2):

- [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org)
- [Burp Proxy](http://portswigger.net/proxy/)
- [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com)
- [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com)
- [WebScarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project)

Comment: All these are great programs, but if you have noticed, http analyzer is very easy and can group connections by process name (ex. Firefox.exe) and this is great specially for non specialist-users.
any other suggestions please ??